# Emacs: How do I set flycheck to Python 3?

Tags: python, emacs

I've installed flycheck for Emacs Python on Ubuntu 15.04.

However, when using the tool it reports false positives like `print(item, end=' ')` is wrong syntax due to `end`.

I know this is Python 3 syntax, and that the syntax error is caused by flycheck is set up for Python 2.

**How do I set flycheck up for Python 3?**

In the documentation on Github, it doesn't mention whether it supports Python 2 or 3 (just Python).

Also, if possible, give me a hint why the elpa tool is not giving suggestions for e.g. basic Python types.

My init.el file is here:

```
;; init.el --- Emacs configuration

;; INSTALL PACKAGES
;; -------------------------------------

(require 'package)

;; Primary Emacs repository is MELPA
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)
(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))

(defvar myPackages
  '(better-defaults
    elpy ;; Emacs Lisp Python Environment
    flycheck ;; flycheck Python syntax-checking
    material-theme))

(mapc #'(lambda (package)
      (unless (package-installed-p package)
        (package-install package)))
      myPackages)

;; BASIC CUSTOMIZATION
;; -------------------------------------

(setq inhibit-startup-message t) ;; hide startup message
(load-theme 'material t) ;; load material theme
(global-linum-mode t) ;; enable line numbers globally
(global-flycheck-mode) ;; enable flycheck globally

;; PYTHON CONFIGURATION
;; -------------------------------------
(elpy-enable) ;; enable elpy

;; use flycheck, not flymake with elpy
(when (require 'flycheck nil t)
  (setq elpy-modules (delq 'elpy-module-flymake elpy-modules))
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(python-shell-interpreter "python3"))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

;; init.el ends here
```

Comment: I've had the same issue with the `await` and `async` keywords and of course the `print` function

Answer (score 20):

Flycheck has a number of checkers for each [supported language](https://flycheck.readthedocs.io/en/latest/languages.html) (and many more [provided by the community](https://flycheck.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community/extensions.html)). Nearly all of them use external tools to check buffers and most of them can be configured.

The easiest way to find out what checkers are supported and how to configure them is by introspection. Open a python file and call `flycheck-verify-setup` or press `C-c ! v`. This shows you a new buffer with a list of syntax checkers used in python-mode. Every checker is a hyperlink to the documentation where it is described and the configuration options are given.

Since I don't have `python-flake8` nor `python-pylint` I just set the variable `flycheck-python-pycompile-executable` to `"python3"` and all is bright and cheerful.

Answer (score 17):

For my case (no pipenv), I got it working by installing the checkers into `python3`:

```
$ pip3 install flake8 pylint mypy
```

And adding the following to my `~/.emacs.c/custom.el` so Flycheck uses `python3` for the checkers:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(flycheck-python-flake8-executable "python3")
 '(flycheck-python-pycompile-executable "python3")
 '(flycheck-python-pylint-executable "python3"))
```

As @uwe-koloska noted, using <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> to call `flycheck-verify-setup` is very helpful!

Comment: Nice, I used your snippet to have flake and pylint use the virtual env (venv) of the current project. I replaced "python3" with ".venv/bin/python3" in your snippet. That is working so far (obviously this requires that you always store your virtual environment in the `.venv` directory of the current project.

Answer (score 9):

Flycheck simply calls the pylint executable that should be somewhere in your path. If that executable was installed by pip for python2 then pylint will check python2 syntax if it was installed for pip (sometimes called pip3) for python3 then pylint will check python3 syntax.

How to proceed depends on a number of things.

If you are using virtual environments then a good place to start is [on this page](https://github.com/lunaryorn/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/flycheck-virtualenv.el) from flycheck's creator's dotfiles

This line is also necessary: `(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'flycheck-virtualenv-setup)`

If you are not using virtual environments then you can just make sure that the pylint executable was installed for python3

Comment: Does Python 2 syntax valid Python 3 syntax?

Comment: For the most part, there are some differences though. For example python3 does not have `execfile` and a few other things such as reduce

Answer (score 2):

As @Jules mentioned:

> Flycheck simply calls the pylint executable that should be somewhere
>   in your path.

So it becomes critical that the correct flake8 version is accessible within emacs. Since you are using `pipenv`, you should be sure to first install `flake8` within your project's environment, and then ensure that your environment is activated before launching emacs.

From within your project root directory:

```
pipenv install flake8
pipenv shell
```

You can then launch emacs from the commandline, and flycheck will connect with the correct version of flake8 for your project.