# emacs flycheck-mode python3 print statement with file=sys.stderr

Tags: python, python-3.x, emacs, flycheck

I am using emacs on Ubuntu 16.04 and added the configuration for flycheck-mode to include the python3 setup below:

[Emacs: How do I set flycheck to Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720869/emacs-how-do-i-set-flycheck-to-python-3)

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55000284/719016

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(flycheck-python-flake8-executable "python3")
 '(flycheck-python-pycompile-executable "python3")
 '(flycheck-python-pylint-executable "python3"))
```

But my python3 buffer still gives me an `invalid syntax [E0001]` error in a line like below:

```py
print("# My message for the stderr", file=stderr)
```

The syntax checkers loaded are python-pylint and python-pycompile (for some reason python-flake8 does not seem to be found.

Any ideas why?

Comment: do you import `stderr`? install `flake8`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you took the answer that you quoted literally, your configuration isn't getting loaded. The answer suggests putting the config in `~/.emacs.c/custom.el`. That's a typo. The correct path is `~/.emacs.d/custom.el`. The more correct answer is to put the config in the file pointed to by `custom-file`. The most correct answer is to never edit the custom file by hand. Instead use the `customize` facility.

- Run `M-x customize-group flycheck`.
- Scroll to the bottom of the buffer and click on "Flycheck executables".
- Find the python executables you want to change. (Always use `python3` for Python3 stuff, even if you *only* have Python3 on your system. It'll save you headaches later.)
- Scroll to the top of the buffer.
- Click "Apply and Save".
- Boom. Your settings are saved in the correct "`custom.el`" file.

Now, load up a Python3 file you want to use `flycheck` with. If it's not doing what you expect, check things with `C-c ! v` (aka `flycheck-verify-setup`.) Confirm individual checkers with `C-c ! ?` (aka `flycheck-describe-checker`.) Check the variables you think you're setting with `C-h v`. Cut-n-paste them from `flycheck`'s website if you have to.

Don't worry about `flake8`'s config file. It will properly cascade as you expect.

And, lastly, as @jenesaisquois suggests:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
print("# My message for the stderr", file=sys.stderr)
```